# REST API - Can I authenticate an Android app without having the client id/secret?

Tags: rest-api, oauth

Anyone know if it's possible to authenticate with SF from an external app (ie an Android app, or a Java application) without the client having the "Client Key" and the "Client Secret?"

I'd rather not have to embed the client key/secret in my app (or in a config file that ships with the app) since the app will be used across many different SalesForce orgs.

Based on what I've read in the mobile SDK guide and the OAuth articles for SF, I'm not sure this is even possible, but I'd love to hear what people with similar situations are doing!

Comment: If you're OAuthing via a Connected App on Salesforce, don't believe you can do it without the consumer key and secret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need at least the client Key, however there is no need for every org to have its own key, you can define your remote access (aka connected app) record once,and its usable everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. When you say that only one remote access record is needed, where does that remote access record reside in a multi-org environment? Would that just be something that I would set up in my partner org and use it as the basis for authenticating across all my client's orgs? 

I apologize for my ignorance here, just wasn't very clear from the mobile SDK guide...

Comment: You can create it any org, and then use it from any other org. so you could create it in your partner org, or in a DE org.